# Understanding queueing theory used to model the vehicle routing problem

Tags: reference-request, vehicle-routing, queuing-theory, stochastic-process

I am trying to understand some journal articles on the vehicle routing problem, specifically [Vehicle routing with dynamic travel times: A queueing approach](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220288626_Vehicle_routing_with_dynamic_travel_times_A_queueing_approach) and [An M/M/c queue model for vehicle routing problem in multi-door cross-docking environments](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0305054821002550), but have a limited background in queueing theory especially when it comes it applications of queueing theory to the vehicle routing problem. Can anyone provide any resources that explain how queueing theory is used to model the vehicle routing problem or give any advice on how to understand the mathematics used in these articles?